# Facebook login SDK app ID

Tags: swift, facebook

Yesterday I created a new project simple to try to create a viewcontroller with an facebook login. I had sucess.

However, today I decided to implement the facebook login in one of my other app projects, but now when I run my app I get this error:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidOperationException', reason: 'App ID not found. Add a string value with your app ID for the key FacebookAppID to the Info.plist or call [FBSDKSettings setAppID:].'

In my info.plist my app ID is set to the right ID (I did check at the SDK facebook website to make sure it was the same ID used there as well)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two info.plist files. In your project folder there is one file and inside your project's tests folder there is another one too. Give the app id to it.